# how to change label content with a button in different user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I have a main project and a class library project. In the class library project i also have 2 user controls(wpf) and one of them has a button and the other one has a label.

Here is my question. How can i change label content with button click in this solution file in c#?

Comment: Please learn MVVM before ever writing a single line of code in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore I sometimes wish VS would put that as a comment at the top of MainWindow in every WPF project it creates.